# How many numbers in the right spot?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have a deck of $N$ cards numbered $1$ thru $N$. Suppose we shuffle the cards as to randomize, how many cards do we expect to be in the right spot?

For example a $3$ in the $3rd$ spot is a $3$ in the right spot.

---

My work:

Let $p(x)$ count the number of permutations with $x$ amount of numbers in the right place the expected value is,

$$\sum_{x=0}^{N} x\frac{p(x)}{N!}$$

$$=\frac{1}{N!} \sum_{x=0}^{N} x p(x)$$

Conceptually $f(N)=\sum_{x=0}^{N} x p(x)$ is the total number in the right place from all permutations combined.

By hand I worked out $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, $f(3)=3$, and $f(4)=24$.

So I conjecture the answer to be $1$ card for all $N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Your conjecture is true.

Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable that the $i$-th card is at the right position.

You are interested in computing $\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\right]$.

Comment: Is  $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{N}$ because their should be equal probability that the other card is any of the $N$ numbers, and so the the probability that the $ith$ card is $i$ is $\frac{1}{N}$?

Comment: yup, you got the hint well. =)

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

This can be proven combinatorically as well, using the so-called *derangement* numbers $D_n$ ($D_n$ is the number of permutations of numbers 1 through $n$ where none of the numbers stand in their proper place). Proof to your conjecture immediately follows from the following formula for derangement numbers
$$
n! = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}D_{n-k} \qquad \qquad (*)
$$

A very nice question, though — thanks for the reminder! I haven't used derangement numbers in quite a while.

Comment: Proof of the formula itself immediately follows from the fact that in any of the $n!$ permutations several numbers are in their proper places while all the others are not. So both sides of formula (*) count the number of all possible permutations of n elements/numbers.